# How do I web scrape with beautiful soup an element without class or id

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the amount of money for the "Next Jackpot" on this website http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/product/Pages/toto_results.aspx using beautiful soup but I am having difficulties in getting the 1,000,000 (currently)

I am currently going through the book: automate the boring stuff with python. I have spent almost 2 hours reading online tutorials and past questions here but I still cant figure out how to do it for an element without class or id which most tutorials show

```
import requests, bs4
res=requests.get('http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/product/Pages/toto_results.aspx')
res.raise_for_status()
noStarchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
elems = noStarchSoup.find('span', {'style':'color'}, {'style':'font-weight'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to network tab you will find below url.

http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/DataFileArchive/Lottery/Output/toto_next_draw_estimate_en.html?v=2019y8m29d17h15m

Use the below code to retrieve the value.

```
import requests, bs4
import re
res=requests.get('http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/DataFileArchive/Lottery/Output/toto_next_draw_estimate_en.html?v=2019y8m29d17h15m')
res.raise_for_status()
noStarchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
elems = noStarchSoup.find('div',text=re.compile('Next Jackpot')).find_next('span')
print(elems.text)
```

Output:

```
$1,000,000 est
```

Comment: I guess this will work, but for bonus points we should point out that the query param `v` is hardcoded. OP should build this string by date

Comment: @RafaelT : JavaScripts render to the page.I believe selenium with bs4 should work fine.

Comment: I just meant the param val is `v=2019y8m29d17h15m` which looks like a timestamp to me. OP should build this to get current values and not the same every day

Comment: Thx for the answer, is it a good practice to check the network tab when doing webscraping to isolate/ reduce the html you need to look at? A beginner here.

Comment: Yes if it dynamic page then you need to check Network tab and look for API

Comment: By network tab, do u mean the network tab when u inspect in chrome browser?
Do we always look at sub-tab XHR? Since that where I can find url you provided